# Singular method to retrieve data from SQL Server for various stored procedures, how to handle parameters?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a single method on my SQL helper class, along with an overload to accept a parameter:

```
public static DataTable GetData(string cmd_text)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    SqlConnection conn = GetSqlConnection();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand
    {
        CommandText = cmd_text,
        CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure,
        Connection = conn
    };

    using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
    {
        da.Fill(dt);
    }

    return dt;
}
```

Overload:

```
public static DataTable GetData(string cmd_text, string p1)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    SqlConnection conn = GetSqlConnection();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand
    {
        CommandText = cmd_text,
        CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure,
        Connection = conn
    };

    //add parameter here somehow?

    using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
    {
        da.Fill(dt);
    }

    return dt;
}
```

However, it occurred to me part way through that I need to pass the same parameter name that the stored procedure expects. I could always get around this by having another argument in my method for the name of the parameter, or even by adjusting the parameters in SQL Server to just all be the same on all of my stored procedures, but I was wondering if this could be handled another way, either on the C# or SQL end.

My theory on how this could be accomplished was to build a wrapper stored procedure that could call other stored procedures, but I'm not entirely sure how that could be implemented if even possible.

Comment: and you always just have one parameter that is of type string? never other datatypes never more than one parameter?

Comment: Where are the parameters coming from? If the SP is "looking" for the parameters, you would set them with the `cmd.Parameters.Add(...)`.

Comment: Use a `IDictionary<string,object> p` where the key is the paramName and the object is the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `IDictionary<string,object> p` where the key is the paramName and the object is the value.

```
public static DataTable GetData(string cmd_text, IDictionary<string, object> p1)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    SqlConnection conn = GetSqlConnection();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand
    {
        CommandText = cmd_text,
        CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure,
        Connection = conn
    };

    
    foreach (var p in p1)
    {
        //add parameter here
    }

    using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
    {
        da.Fill(dt);
    }

    return dt;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Step 0: stop using `DataTable`

Step 1: use Dapper

There is no step 2.

Simply:

```cs
string bar = "ABC"; // just to show usage
var data = connection.Query<YourPoco>(
    "SomeSpName",
    new { foo = 12, bar }, // named args
    commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).AsList();
```

Comment: @Austin it works just fine with stored procedures, as shown in the example, so: if you prefer that route, that's still fine

Answer (score 1):

And ideas what you could do:

- on program start query all sp's and all parameters belonging to the sp
- cache them somewhere
- before calling the sp get the parameter from the cache and adapt your SqlCommand

Here the query to get your information out of the db

```
SELECT 
   SCHEMA_NAME(SCHEMA_ID) AS [Schema]
  ,SO.name AS [ObjectName]             
  ,SO.Type_Desc AS [ObjectType]
  ,P.parameter_id AS [ParameterID]
  ,P.name AS [ParameterName]
  ,TYPE_NAME(P.user_type_id) AS [ParameterDataType]
  ,P.max_length AS [ParameterMaxBytes]
  ,P.is_output AS [IsOutPutParameter]
FROM sys.objects AS SO
INNER JOIN sys.parameters AS P ON SO.OBJECT_ID = P.OBJECT_ID
ORDER BY [Schema], SO.name, P.parameter_id
```

(However I don't think this will get you far at some point you will need more than one parameter and other datatypes and fancy stuff.
I would use EF or as suggested by Marc Dapper. The Era of DataSet and Friends is over.)

Comment: @Austin look Marc's answer. I think that's the best option of all.